# .htaccess rewriting a URL which is passing parameters

Tags: .htaccess

Assume that i'm having a URL like this

```
example.com/demo/index.php?name=test
```

Now I need to rewrite the above URL like this,

```
example.com/demo/test
```

My question is, how can I achieve that by .htaccess URL rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

yuppp, I got it

```
RewriteRule ^demo/([\w-]+)$  demo.php?id=$1
```

Credit to : @Abhishek Gurjar

Comment: Please consider using the real http server's host configuration to implement such rules instead of distributed configuration files (".htaccess").

Comment: @arkascha can you please deeply tell me for how to better access this

Comment: Want to keep example.com/demo/index.php?name=test
test name in every link like

example.com/demo/test/product/12

Comment: Although this does not do quite what you were asking in the question?

Comment: The rule is perfectly OK, though variants or alternatives exist. But the apache http server offers different locations where to implement such a rule. Usually the better location is _not_ distributed configuration files (".htaccess"), but the real host configuration, for a number of reasons. Maybe you want to read a bit about that in the documentation. It is just a suggestion, what you do here will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(.+) /test.php?name=$1 [L]
```

you must add bove code in htaccess and you can get parameter as $_GET['name']